# Can changing one signals duty cycle in a dual signal PWM create a dead time?

Tags: pwm

I have a 2 channel PWM which I intend to control a full bridge gate driver setup, however I need to insert some dead time between the signals. Will changing the duty cycle to 1 of the signals to say 5% lower than the other work?

Comment: That would make it asymmetrical which needs to be raked up by either current control or series capacitor in order not to saturate your transformer. Also your max and/or min duty cycle would be artificially capped.

Comment: And it wouldn't necessarily solve the shoot-through problem if one edge of both signals was still transitioning at the same time.

Comment: Veldox, there is no escaping a careful examination of your PWM peripherals (which we cannot see and therefore cannot evaluate) and their timing and timing controls. It may be possible. Some MCUs actually are specified to be paired up to create easily programmed dead time. (MIcrochip makes some, for example.) But to just blindly say "yes" or "no" here would be just a shot in the dark, with as much info as we have.

Comment: _"Will changing the duty cycle to 1 of the signals to say 5% lower than the other work?"_ - you tried it, right? So did it work?

Answer (score 1):

With matched thresholds and load impedance the common way is to use slower turn and fast turn off for each.  You choose RC for slow and diode RC for fast. Dead time is the difference in xx0 ns to 1.x us depending on FET & load delay differences in performance.

Other ways use XOR logic delays.

- example 100 ns using fast CMOS logic inverters and Si signal diodes.

[image]

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, thanks for the schematic, will this work ok for isolated gate drivers?

Comment: Only if you compute the current delay gain properly